# Nested Listview with vertical Alignment

Tags: c#, listview, grid, uwp-xaml

I want to show nested listview in a manner that the sub items of main item should display on right side of Main Items. And subitems should display if user clicks on any Main items only.

```
 <ListView x:Name="list1" Background="Blue" Width="200" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Main">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ItemName}" />
                    <ListView x:Name="list2" ItemsSource="{x:Bind SubItemsList}" Grid.Row="1">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Sub">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{x:Bind SubItemName}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

When using above code I'm getting Main items in a row and it's subitems in another row.

```
Main 1
 Sub 1
 Sub 1
Main 2
 Sub 2
 Sub 2
```

But my output should be

```
Main Items    Sub Items  
Main 1        Sub 1
              Sub 1
Main 2        Sub 2
              Sub 2
```

If user clicks on Main 1, it should display its Sub items and so on. otherwise no need to display Sub Items. Is it possible by making any changes on above code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use FlyoutMenu control for that, as the requirement you are asking cannot be fulfilled by using a ListView. A ListView will display all the Main and SubItems irrespective of it being clicked or not. A FlyoutMenu, however, works exactly as you have asked here. It displays the SubItems on being clicked, with the provision to display it on the right side (or any side you choose to).

[The microsoft link for the basic idea of Flyout menu](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=bob%20tabor%20flyout&rlz=1C1GGGE___IN672IN672&oq=bob%20tabor%20flyout&aqs=chrome..69i57.6729j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

[A video tutorial to get you up and running with it right away](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Store-apps-for-Absolute-Beginners-with-C-/Part-21-Implementing-an-AppBar-and-Flyout)

Hope this helped you !!